# Create Custom Loss Function in Catboost

Tags: python, loss-function, custom-function, catboost, catboostregressor

I´m trying to create a customized loss function to use in Catboost. This is the function that I'm trying to implement:

```
class ErrorLoss(object):
    def calc_ders_range(self, approxes, targets, weights):
        a = (approxes >= targets)   
        b = sum(a)         
        s = a.shape[0]     
        percentage = b / s   
        error=(targets - approxes)**2  
        cases=targets.shape[0]
        loss=(percentage)+((np.sqrt(sum(error)/cases))/np.mean(targets))
        return loss
```

And this is the error I get when I train the model

```
CatBoostError:line 11, in calc_ders_range
    a = (approxes >= targets)
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of '_catboost._DoubleArrayWrapper' and '_catboost._FloatArrayWrapper'
```

This is the model that I am trying to train

```
model = CatBoostRegressor(iterations=20,
                          learning_rate=0.001,
                          loss_function = ErrorLoss(), eval_metric = 'MAE')
```

Comment: You are trying to compare different types of objects. Only homogeneous comparison is allowed in python. In other words, apples can be compared to apples only. Also, in the present code `a` will have a `boolean` value even if comparison between `approxes` and `targets` is successful. Please mention how you are assigning values to these two variable and operations performed on them

Comment: @smartymcfly So how could I get the percentage of the predictions that are bigger than  the real values? In other words, what I want to simulate is the "approxes" to be y_pred and "targets" be y_true. What type of object usually takes approxes and targets? Are the arrays, or what are they?

Comment: Yes they have to be arrays, but similar type of arrays. Convert both to float type arrays (right now only one is float type)

Comment: @smartymcfly Even having both as float type, I still get the following error: `b = sum(a)
TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable`

Comment: check my first comment again. `a = (approxes >= targets)`. This assigns `True` or `False`. Use `if` , `else` clause.